# Klov installation failed

Tags: automation

Currently, I am using klov tool to generate reports.

First I am installed MongoDB 3.2 then I start the MongoDB server.

Then I am trying to install klov 0.1.0 on command prompt

Using: `java -jar klov-0.1.0.jar` command

when the jar file executed it gives an exception: "APPLICATION FAILED TO START"

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2018-05-03 11:37:02.009  INFO 9308 --- [           main] com.aventstack.klov.Application          : Starting Application v0.1.0 on CS69-PC with PID 9308 (E:\klov-0.1.0\klov-0.1.0.jar started by ADMIN in E:\klov-0.1.0)
2018-05-03 11:37:02.017  INFO 9308 --- [           main] com.aventstack.klov.Application          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-03 11:37:02.233  INFO 9308 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1698c449: startup date [Thu May 03 11:37:02 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy2018-05-03 11:37:13.732  INFO 9308 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/auth/signout],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.aventstack.klov.controllers.UserController.signout(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2018-05-03 11:37:13.736  INFO 9308 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-05-03 11:37:13.740  INFO 9308 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-05-03 11:37:13.808  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-03 11:37:13.812  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-03 11:37:13.844  INFO 9308 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
2018-05-03 11:37:13.950  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-05-03 11:37:14.440  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1698c449: startup date [Thu May 03 11:37:02 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-03 11:37:14.469  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-05-03 11:37:14.474  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-05-03 11:37:14.476  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-05-03 11:37:14.478  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-05-03 11:37:14.483  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-05-03 11:37:14.486  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-05-03 11:37:14.495  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.497  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.499  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.501  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.515  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.517  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.519  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.526  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/ || /rest],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
2018-05-03 11:37:14.529  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/ || /rest],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
2018-05-03 11:37:14.530  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/ || /rest],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
2018-05-03 11:37:14.537  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.541  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.547  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.549  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.551  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.553  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.561  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.564  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.568  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.573  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.575  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/rest/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-05-03 11:37:14.585  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/rest/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.589  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/rest/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
2018-05-03 11:37:14.593  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/rest/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2018-05-03 11:37:14.596  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/rest/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
2018-05-03 11:37:14.598  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/rest/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2018-05-03 11:37:14.895  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-03 11:37:15.025 ERROR 9308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:250) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:193) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
        at com.aventstack.klov.Application.main(Application.java:45) [classes!/:0.1.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [klov-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [klov-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [klov-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [klov-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1021) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
        ... 22 common frames omitted

2018-05-03 11:37:15.051  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-05-03 11:37:15.088  INFO 9308 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-03 11:37:15.099 ERROR 9308 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 80, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2018-05-03 11:37:15.105  INFO 9308 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1698c449: startup date [Thu May 03 11:37:02 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-03 11:37:15.114  INFO 9308 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-05-03 11:37:15.129  INFO 9308 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:5}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

Please give me any suggestions or solution

Comment: Start the app on a different port, 81 for example.  See the error:  "Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 80, or configure this application to listen on another port."

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is that:

*"The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured."*

In the Klov folder locate and open **application.properties**

```
# klov
application.name=LibraBank
application.display.proLabels=false
server.port=80
```

Change the *server.port=80* to any other port e.g. *server.port=2571*